# Changing hostname and port with Vapor 3

Tags: swift, docker, vapor

The Config/server.json file doesn't seem to be read by Vapor 3, and as such I can't configure the hostname and port that a Vapor 3 app binds to.

Does Vapor 3 have a different method for this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Currently, you can set the port and hostname when running your server:

`swift run Run --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 9000`

There [appears to be](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/beta/Sources/Vapor/Engine/EngineServer.swift#L270) struct-based configuration for `EngineServer` but I don’t think it is configurable at run time just yet. The last time the Vapor developer answered this question (on their Slack) the command-line argument method was the suggested one.

Comment: We do use struct based configurations, although those are still configurable though Services.

Comment: we can use our ip address in the replacement of 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 27):

### Official Solution (as sanctioned by the maintainers)

You can use NIOServerConfig.

```
let serverConfiure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0", port: 9090)
services.register(serverConfiure)
```

Vapor version is 3.0.3

Comment: This is the officially sanctioned one: I asked maintainers.

Comment: This works great. I wrapped it in development.... if env == .development {
        let serverConfiure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0", port: 9090)
        services.register(serverConfiure)
    }

Answer (score 18):

**in Vapor 4**

```
app.http.server.configuration.hostname = "127.0.0.1"
app.http.server.configuration.port = 8000
```

**in Vapor 3**

```
services.register(NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "127.0.0.1", port: 8000))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Vapor 4, as shown in their [docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/server/#port). Do this in `public func configure(_ app: Application) throws`.

Comment: This thing works like a charm for vapor 4. Thanks man!

Answer (score 7):

Be sure you are using the Vapor 3 version then use this:

```
vapor run --hostname=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

If you **don't add** `=` after the parameter, you are going to receive the follow complaint:

```
CommandError: Unknown command 8080
```

If you do as I recommended above, you are going to receive:

```
[Deprecated] --option=value syntax is deprecated.
```

Please use --option value (with no =) instead but the command will run and works fine.

I was unable to find a way to run this command without `=` after the parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Editing the Run scheme's "Arguments Passed on Launch" also worked for me

[image][image]

Answer (score 5):

My $0.02

```
import Vapor

/// Called before your application initializes.
///
/// [Learn More →](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/structure/#configureswift)
public func configure(
    _ config: inout Config,
    _ env: inout Environment,
    _ services: inout Services
    ) throws {
    if env == .development {
        services.register(Server.self) { container -> EngineServer in
            var serverConfig = try container.make() as EngineServerConfig
            serverConfig.port = 8989
            serverConfig.hostname = "192.168.31.215"
            let server = EngineServer(
                config: serverConfig,
                container: container
            )
            return server
        }
    }

    //Other configure code
}
```

It works perfectly on Vapor 3.0.0 RC 2.4.1

Comment: For Vapor 3.3.0, 'EngineServerConfig' is deprecated: renamed to 'NIOServerConfig'; and, 'EngineServer' is deprecated: renamed to 'NIOServer'.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the hostname and port with command line flags:

`--hostname localhost --port 8080`

Answer (score 1):

You could also register your `EngineServerConfig` in `services`.

In `configure.swift`, insert the code below:

```
let myServerConfig = try EngineServerConfig.detect(from: &env, port: 8081)
services.register(myServerConfig)
```

This should work for `3.0.0-rc.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

In vapor: stable 3.1.10

open: configure.swift

In: public func configure()

Add the following:

```
// Define Hostname & Port to listen to ...
let myServerConfig = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "servers-hostname.local", port: 8080)
services.register(myServerConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

What iOS Guy had written needs a bit of modification for Vapor 3.3.1
`// Define Hostname & Port to listen to ...
let myServerConfig = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "localhost", port: 8081)
services.register(myServerConfig)`

So `NIOServerConfig.default` can be used only with two parameters hostname & port and it can be used if one just wants to change the port number.